# Python Discord Bot - Restrict Commands for only 1 chat

Tags: discord, discord.py

So i have this command that i want to only be used in 1 chat. How would i restrict it from working in other chats than the chat called "general".
I got other commands that needs to be working in all chats so i cant just restrict the bots perms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own [`check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#checks):

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot("!")

def in_channel(*channels):
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.channel.id in channels
    return commands.check(predicate)

@in_channel(channel_id)
@bot.command()
async def command_name(ctx, ...):
    ...

bot.run("token")
```